# Multiple "Views" of the same table in excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, datamodel

I am currently managing invoice payments in Excel and was wondering if there is any way to create multiple editable tables that display the exact same (synchronized) data.

Essentially, I want multiple filters active on the same table at once so I can (for example) open up all transfers from a single creditor to the right one side of my screen, while looking through all bank statements on the other (while being able to edit the data in **both** tables).

I have looked into excel Data Models but I am not sure if what I am asking for is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Excel allows you to view two windows of the same sheet. Give this a try. https://www.excelcampus.com/tips/new-window/

Comment: That doesn't work

Comment: Filtering in one view results in the same filter being applied on the table in the other view.